# How I can utilise json with scala?

Tags: json, scala

I utilise IntelliJ and not sbt.
I have a task where I need to create a post. I need to enter this information:

```
{
"packages": [
    {
        "uid": "...",
        "x": 21.27,
        "y": 23.36
    },
    {
        "uid": "...",
        "x": -16.01,
        "y": -12.82
    },
    {
        "uid": "...",
        "x": 19.38,
        "y": 1.77
    }
],
"mailmen": [
    {
        "uid": "...",
        "x": 14.68,
        "y": 9.69
    },
    {
        "uid": "...",
        "x": 0.08,
        "y": -3.34
    }
]
```

}

And I've done the programm and I have classes:

```
    class livreur(var uid:String,var xMaison:Double,var yMaison:Double,var x:Double,var y:Double,var distance:Double=0.0){
      def afficherL : Unit ={
      println("Uid "+uid)
      println("Distance: "+distance)
    }
  }
class packages(var uid:String,var x:Double,var y:Double,var uidLivre:String=""){
    def afficherP : Unit ={
      println("Uid "+uid)
    }
  }
```

Functions which I utilise to create objects:

```
    def saisirLivreur():livreur={
      val uidLiv=readLine("Uid: ").toString
      val xMaison=readLine("X: ").toDouble
      val yMaison=readLine("Y: ").toDouble
      return new livreur(uidLiv,xMaison,yMaison,xMaison,yMaison)
    }

    def saisirPackage():packages={
      val uidPack=readLine("Uid: ").toString
      val xPack=readLine("X: ").toDouble
      val yPack=readLine("Y: ").toDouble
      return new packages(uidPack,xPack,yPack)
    }
```

**My questions are: 
how I can connect my class with input information and how I can output the information in format which I need in the end if I have 2 ArraysBuffers, 1st  with all couriers (livrMaison)  and 2nd with all delivered packages (packagesLivré). :

```
[
{
    "uid": "uid-du-livreur",
    "tour": [  //liste des colis à distribuer, dans l'ordre
        "uid-du-premier-colis-de-la-tournee-de-ce-livreur"
    ],
    "length": 28.670242284303 //longueur totale du parcours
},
{
    "uid": "uid-du-livreur",
    "tour": [ //liste des colis à distribuer, dans l'ordre
        "uid-du-premier-colis-de-la-tournee-de-ce-livreur",
        "uid-du-second-colis-de-la-tournee-de-ce-livreur"
    ],
    "length": 106.54693343859 //longueur totale du parcours
}
```

]
** 
Please help me.
Thanks,-N

Comment: Hi Nikita :-) Thanks for taking the time to correcty format your question ! However, it's currently hard to say what is the problem exactly.  Is it affecting packages to mailmen to have short delivery circuits ? Is it parsing input some more ? 

Please expand on where you're blocking, now that what you have done is quite clear :-)

Comment: @C4stor,I am beginner in scala. I didn't understand your questions. I've editted my question. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Classes in scala should be Upper case `Livreur` instead of `livreur`
- to parse and produce json use one of existing libraries. I propose `upickle` (http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/) (add `ibraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.9.5"` to `build.sbt`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to install something?

Comment: It depend what you are using to run your scala code. If `sbt` then you just need to add dependency.

Comment: I don't know what is it sbt. I use IntelliJ.

Comment: Ok then. You are learning scala and you try to solve non trivial problem (there is no build in tools for json in scala library). My suggestion is to create simplest sbt project that will contain only what you need.

Comment: @NikitaShimolin I know that it could be harder than you though, but trust me, knowing how to use any library in your code is what you will need at some point. `Sbt` is currently nota bene standard in scala ecosystem and you will not regret lerning it. I guess you already have `sbt` project, if no create one from Intelij Idea, and add `libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.9.5"` to `build.sbt`. Then read ducumentation http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/ and experiment with it a bit.

Comment: Ask If you stuck, but be patient a bit. Sbt is tough, don't try to understand it too much right now. You need to add dependency and maybe run code. There is much more in this tool but it is much harder and most of the time not necessary.

Comment: thank you for your advices. I begin to study sbt, but I need to do my project tomorrow. Can you please write the begining and the end for my code with using the upickle becausee I can't understand how you can input the information with my fonctions and how to output the information from an Array?